# Adding tabset to a specific column within a row, flexdashboard, R

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am looking to add a tabset to just one of the windows in my flexdashboard layout. Here is the basic layout of my dashboard:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
   
---


library(flexdashboard)


row 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A


### Chart B



Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Chart C
```

The layout when rendering looks like the following:
[image]

How can I change this code so that there are two tabs on columns A and B? I tried adding {.tabset} next to the row headers, but this does not seem to support adding another window in another column. Any help would be greatly appreciated!